# Sets in ZFC and the order of logic

Tags: logic, set-theory

$
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
$
For example, the well-ordering principle (WOP) states that every nonempty subset of $\N$ has a least element. In symbols:
$$
\forall A \subseteq \N: [A \neq \varnothing \Rightarrow \exists x \in A:\forall y \in A: x \le y]
$$
It quantifies over the subsets of $\N$. I've seen that the statement is second-order (SO) because the set of all subsets of $\N$ cannot be expressed in the first-order (FO) logic.

On the other hand, the axiom of power set in ZFC based on FOL, states that every set has a power set. The quantification over the subsets is just the quantification over the element of the power set, i.e., $\forall A \in \mathcal{P}(\N):\phi(A)$. Statements involving the quantification over the elements of sets, which are also sets, is FO.

On this (possibly incorrect) base knowledge, why does WOP has to be SO? I guess the reason is that the construction of the set of all subsets of $\N$ infeasible in FO in the first place. As a result, $\forall A \subseteq \N:\phi(A)$ is SO.

If this observation is correct, given that the set $B$ of subsets of some set can be constructed in FOL, is the sentence $\forall A \in B: \phi(A)$ in FOL?

What introduction-level textbooks do you recommend to clarify the notions required to answer the question? The only logic book I've read so far is Barker-Plummer's Language, Proof and Logic (2011), but it does not describe much about SOL.

Comment: I don't really understand the decision to close. The answer is quite different from what I am looking for :(

Comment: The WOP is a second order statement in the language of arithmetic. Since ZFC interprets the second order structure of the natural numbers, it is a first order statement in the context of ZFC.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you. Your comment helps a lot, but I don't still understand why the post is closed without a voting process excluding any chance for me to explain why it's not specifically an answer to my question. There remain other questions unanswered as you know.

Comment: Maybe you have to review the basic concept of [Interpretation for FOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)#First-order_logic9).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for the link! Would you recommend a textbook about the topic? I want to learn the notions from a more credible and comprehensive source.

Comment: Standard ML textbooks; see e.g. [van Dalen](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~mlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf)